# My tax calculator program is almost complete but with a few issues

Tags: java, oop

I am having to [input] the income twice before the program executes the taxes owed & it is only using one tax bracket (10%) to calculate every other tax bracket. My following code is below:

```
package org.tax.tutorial;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Taxability {

    //The main method of this program   
        public static void main(String[] args){

            int userInput = 0;
            double bracketOne = 0.10;
            double bracketTwo = 0.15;
            double bracketThree = 0.25;
            double bracketFour = 0.28;
            double bracketFive = 0.33;
            double bracketSix = 0.35;
            double total = 0.0;


            //Inform user about the program 
            System.out.println("This program is designed to calcualte your annual income and determine how much taxes you currently owe." + "\n");

            //Inform user about tax brackets
            System.out.print("Based on your income you may be classifed under one of the six brackets:" + "\n" + "\n" + "Bracket 1: 0–$8,500 10%" + "\n" + "Bracket 2: $34,500 15%" + "\n" + "Bracket 3: $34,500–$83,600 25%" + "\n" +  "Bracket 4: $83,600–$174,400 28%" + "\n" + "Bracket 5: $174,400–$379,150 33%" + "\n" + "Bracket 6: $379,150 above 35%" + "\n" + "\n");


            {
                //User inputs their annual income
                System.out.println("Please submit your annual income for the following year 2013-2014:");

                //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                userInput = keyboard.nextInt();

                if ((userInput >= 0) & (userInput<= 8500 ));{
                total = bracketOne * keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Total tax owed is $" + total + "\n" + "\n" + "Thank your for using the tax calculator.");
                }
                if ((userInput >=8500) & (userInput <= 34500));{
                total = bracketTwo * keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Total tax owed is $" + total + "\n" + "\n" + "Thank your for using the tax calculator.");

                }
                if ((userInput >=34500) & (userInput <= 83600));{
                    total = bracketThree * keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Total tax owed is $" + total + "\n" + "\n" + "Thank your for using the tax calculator.");
                    System.exit(0);
                    }
                if ((userInput >=83600) & (userInput <= 174400));{
                    total = bracketFour * keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Total tax owed is $" + total + "\n" + "\n" + "Thank your for using the tax calculator.");

                }
                if ((userInput >=174400) & (userInput <= 379150));{
                    total = bracketFive * keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Total tax owed is $" + total + "\n" + "\n" + "Thank your for using the tax calculator.");

                }
                if (userInput >=379150);{
                    total = bracketSix * keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Total tax owed is $" + total + "\n" + "\n" + "Thank your for using the tax calculator.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This site works better when you ask a question.

Comment: Ill just randomly choose a number that ranges from either 0-379,150. The program executes the calculation correctly for the first tax bracket which is 10% but anything after 8,500 it will just use the same percentage for taxes owed.

Comment: And I have to input the number twice before the program executes the calculation

Comment: On top of what David Wallace has in his answer you may want to try entering these values as your income as the output might not be what you expect. Try each of these value as income: 8500, 34500, 83600, 174400, 379150

Comment: @brittneyjava: those were statements. On this site we answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

(1) You are reading input once with `userInput = keyboard.nextInt();` and again with `keyboard.nextDouble()`.  I think you want to re-use the result from the first call, instead of requiring more input.  So change every occurrence of `keyboard.nextDouble()` to `userInput`, which is the variable where you have stored the initial input.

(2) You have some extra `;` characters after each `if` statement - the ones between `)` and `{`.  Remove them.

(3) Problems with rounding errors.  It's really better to use `BigDecimal` rather than `double` for financial calculations, if you want exact answers.  I'm not sure whether or not you've learnt about `BigDecimal` in your course.

(4) There are a few values that occur in more than one of your `if` statements.  You need to be a bit more careful about the difference between `<` and `<=`, and between `>` and `>=`.

(5) It won't make any difference in this case, but it's generally better to write `&&` instead of `&` when you mean "AND".  It means that the computer won't bother calculating the right hand side in the case where the left hand side comes out as false.

Comment: I am trying to comprehend your statement. I should switch the keyboard.nextDouble() to keyboard.userInput()?

Comment: No.  At the point where you've written `keyboard.nextDouble()`, you've already got the input.  So forget about `keyboard` entirely and just write `userInput`.

Comment: I appreciate the guidance, learning java completely "online" is harder than attending a course on campus in my opinion.

Comment: That was it! Thanks David.